# RGB array to MIME type image to string

Tags: javascript, c++, opencv, image-processing, ros

I'm working with ROS. I'm subscribing to topic /camera that updates me 30 times per second with message. The message contains width and height of frame and array of ints (0-255). Array looks like:

```
[pixel_1_r, pixel_1_g, pixel_1_b, pixel_2_r, pixel_2_g, pixel_2_b, ...]
```

At the end I want to display camera images in my webserver. To do so, first I need to create MIME type image with that data in C++ code. Then I want to convert that image to string and then I will publish that string on topic /camera_converted. JS will listen to that topic. In JS I will receive string with image, that I have to convert to MIME type and display in img tag.

I am looking for the easiest way to translate RGB array to jpeg/png/whatever with C++ and convert it to string that JS can translate to jpeg/png/whatever and display in img tag.

---

After some adjustments I'm passing some string that should contain .jpeg image and receiving it in JS, image doesn't appear, but no image icon is refreshing
[image]

Comment: libjpeg or libpng seem like the obvious choices?

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this :

inc c++:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

void cameraCallback(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg) {

    cv::Mat image(msg->height, msg->width, CV_8UC3, const_cast<uint8_t*>(msg->data.data()));

    std::vector<uint8_t> jpegData;
    cv::imencode(".jpg", image, jpegData);

    std::string jpegString(jpegData.begin(), jpegData.end());

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "image_converter");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("/camera", 1, cameraCallback);

    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

then in js :

```
const ROSLIB = require('roslib');

const ros = new ROSLIB.Ros();
ros.connect('ws://localhost:9090');
// or whatever your server port is

const imageTopic = new ROSLIB.Topic({
    ros: ros,
    name: '/camera_converted',
    messageType: 'std_msgs/String', // Adjust the message type as needed
});

imageTopic.subscribe(function (message) {
    const imageDataUri = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${message.data}`;
    const img = document.getElementById('cameraImage');
    img.src = imageDataUri;
});
```

Comment: I had similar result before, message published by C++ appears as 
`
- ???
- ???
...
`
when checked with ros2 topic echo, but JS receives `2tra2tra2traAHFSLCE...` type string, that doesn't get translated to .jpeg. We are getting somewhere but it isn't it yet. Let's say C++ is doing his job fine for now. I will keep looking for answers, and I am still following that question.